# Takes 4+ hours to delete 600k rows

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

The code below is taking more than 4 hours to delete 600,000 rows from my workbooks. I need my code to take less time to delete the same amount of data.

```
Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long, Lastrow As Long, Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long, ViewMode As Long
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With
    With ActiveSheet
        .Select 'select sheet so we can change the window view
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View 'go to normal view, for speed
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False 'Turn off Page Breaks
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row  'Set first & last row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1  'loop bottom to top
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    Select Case .Value
                        Case Is <> "jelle", "ron", "dave": .EntireRow.Delete
                    End Select
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With
    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried benchmarking `delete multiple rows at the same time`. For example mark X in the last empty column, filter by `X` value in a column, highlight rows and click DEL. Does that work significantly faster?

Comment: Are you wondering why you deleted 600k rows, but it still takes ages to process now-empty sheet? If so, that is because Excel only truncates `UsedRange` when you save the file.

Comment: I am new to VBA. I had seen some sites and copied this code. i need to delete the large amount of data using vba. i am not sure where it is taking so long time. please help me.

Comment: I had the same issue, the most consuming action by Excel is Deleting. What I ended up doing is actually saving all needed data in an array, and then just copied the array to a new sheet - way faster.

Comment: Why are you checking if the value is an error? If the value is "jelle", "ron", or "dave" then it follows that the cell isn't an error. That is just an extra step that is not needed.

Comment: You are also selecting the active sheet which is redundant - the sheet is already active so this does nothing. Not that this is your problem in speed.

Comment: It's questionable to have 600K rows in Excel, let alone deleting 600K rows. Could your dataset go to 1.049M rows?  Worth a re-think. If not a worry to you, then sort the column A and match the first and last occurrences of those 3 strings. Bulk delete the rows in 3 different operations.

Comment: Yes I am having 600k rows but out of this when I filter with my requirements it is having only 16k rows. so can any one pls tell best way to have only those 16k records out of all 600k records in quicker way(should take less time) which includes header also.

Answer (score 1):

Try building a range during the loop (with `Union`) and then, after the loop, delete all the rows within the range at once. Untested, but something like:

```
Sub Loop_Example()
    Dim Firstrow As Long
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    'We use the ActiveSheet but you can replace this with
    'Sheets("MySheet")if you want
    With ActiveSheet

        'We select the sheet so we can change the window view
        .Select

        'If you are in Page Break Preview Or Page Layout view go
        'back to normal view, we do this for speed
        ViewMode = ActiveWindow.View
        ActiveWindow.View = xlNormalView

        'Turn off Page Breaks, we do this for speed
        .DisplayPageBreaks = False

        'Set the first and last row to loop through
        Firstrow = .UsedRange.Cells(1).Row
        Lastrow = .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row

        Dim rowsToDelete As Range

        'We loop from Lastrow to Firstrow (bottom to top)
        For Lrow = Lastrow To Firstrow Step -1

            'We check the values in the A column in this example
            With .Cells(Lrow, "A")
                If Not IsError(.Value) Then
                    Select Case .Value
                        Case Is <> "jelle", "ron", "dave"
                        If Not (rowsToDelete Is Nothing) Then
                            Set rowsToDelete = Application.Union(rowsToDelete, .EntireRow)
                        Else
                            Set rowsToDelete = .EntireRow
                        End If
                    End Select
                End If
            End With
        Next Lrow
    End With

    rowsToDelete.EntireRow.Delete

    ActiveWindow.View = ViewMode
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

The other thing that could be done to try to speed things up is to read the cells in column A (that you're checking/comparing) into an array -- and then loop through the array itself rather than making 600k calls to the worksheet. As you loop through the array, you'd build a range using `Union`, then delete the range in one call at the very end.

Comment: Hi chillin.., it is hanging my system.